# Rake error: 'rake' is not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I write: `rake db:migrate`

I get this error:

```
C: \ Rails \ myapp> rake db: migrate
'rake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
a program or batch file.
```

I am using `rails v. 3.0.9` and `gem 'rake', '0.8.7'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `rake` is in your path.