# rake is not recognized as an internal or external command, my PATH is set correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am using ruby 1.8.6 and rake 0.8.7 on Windows now. When I type `gem list` in the command line, it shows:

rake (0.8.7)

And my path is set correctly to contain the ruby folder. But I still get the error message:
rake is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: try prefixing it with `bundle exec`

Comment: this question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713986/rake-error-rake-is-not-recognized)

Comment: I don't have bundle installed, and when I tried to install bundle, it gives me error: bundler requires ruby version >= 1.8.7

Comment: Do you have a rake.exe or a rake.bat in the folder that's in your path? If not, try reinstalling the rake gem.

Comment: @LeviStanley Yes, I have rake file without extension in my path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have any files in your path that Windows thinks are executable (.bat, .cmd, or .exe). Usually when Rake is installed, it recognizes you are running on Windows and installs the appropriate `rake.bat` file.

The first thing to try is reinstalling Rake:

```
gem uninstall rake
gem install rake -v=0.8.7
```

If that doesn't work, you can always try running Rake by using the Ruby executable directly:

```
ruby C:\path\to\ruby\bin\rake your_rake_task
```